# SQL Query Group by and order by

Tags: sql

My sql query is like

```
SELECT `speciesname`, sum(`total_species_catch`) as species_catch FROM `species_estimation` GROUP by `speciesid` ORDER by `species_catch` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

It is working fine in localhost phpmyadmin

In server it shows error like

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fimsul.species_estimation.speciesname' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below - may be you don't add `speciesname` in group by clause

```
SELECT `speciesname`, sum(`total_species_catch`) as species_catch 
FROM `species_estimation` GROUP by `speciesname` 
ORDER by `species_catch` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix here is to just include `speciesname` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    speciesname,
    SUM(total_species_catch) AS species_catch
FROM species_estimation
GROUP BY
    speciesname,
    speciesid
ORDER BY
    species_catch DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

It probably also makes sense to include `speciesid` in the `SELECT` clause as well, just in case two names happen to be the same, and the id could be used to distinguish the duplicates.

Note that your current query actually is ANSI compliant, assuming that the `speciesid` uniquely determines the `speciesname`.  If you wanted to use your current version, you could disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, and the query would then run, as you expect.  But, you might want to keep this mode turned on, in general.